# How to process images in order in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a directory that has about 1000 images. In my matlab code, I have to process these images in order by names.( img1.jpg , img2.jpg and so on). Is there a way to read from the images directrory in order so img1.jpg will be processed, then img2.jpg and so on? Thank you in advance.

```
imgFilesDir =dir('pics/*.jpg');

for n=1:length(imgFilesDir)
%read Target image and convert into single
   rgb2= im2single(imread(strcat('pics/',imgFilesDir(n).name)));
   I2 = rgb2gray(rgb2);
end
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working in your code? Just the order?

Comment: I am getting wrong results because of the order of the images. In windows, the images are sorted  in this way img01, img10, img11, img12 and so on. I want to arrange them in this order img01, img02,img03 ...... Could you help me to achieve that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the numerical part with a regular expression, convert from strings to numbers, sort numerically, and apply that order to your strings:

```
imgFilesDirName = {imgFilesDir.name};
[~, ind] = sort(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(imgFilesDirName,'\d+(?=\..*)','match')));
imgFilesDirSorted = imgFilesDir(ind); %// sorted struct
imgFilesDirNameSorted = imgFilesDirName(ind); %// sorted names
```

The numerical part is assumed to be one or more digits right before the file extension.

For example, given

```
imgFilesDirName = {'imag1.jpg', 'imag10.jpg', 'imag11.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img20.jpg'};
```

you get

```
imgFilesDirNameSorted = 
    'imag1.jpg'    'img2.jpg'    'imag10.jpg'    'imag11.jpg'    'img20.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Luis.. but I am getting this error:Undefined function 'regexp' for input arguments of type
'struct'. .. you are using which matlab version? mine is 2013

Comment: I forgot that `dir` outputs a struct, from which you need the `name` field. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Luis, but when I want to read the second images like this: imread(imgFilesDirNameSorted{1}), image img10.jpg is being read not img2.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked ^__________^.  The right way to read the images is imread(imgFilesDirSorted(1)).. Again Thank you Dr. Luis

Comment: I didn't quite understand your latest comments, but I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use

    `[~, intVecSort] = sort(arrayfun(@(x) x.name, r, 'Uniformoutput', false));`

Sorting by date is even a bit shorter

    `[~, intVecSort] = sort(arrayfun(@(x) x.name, r);`

If you would like to have img3 as third name, this works

    `names = arrayfun(@(x) x.name, r, 'Uniformoutput', false);
    names(:, 2) = cellfun(@(x) {length(x)}, names(:, 1));
    [~, intVecSort] = sortrows(names, [2, 1]);`

Comment: Thank you, but then to access the third image in the array, I write r=r(intVecSort); r(3).name I got the wrong image img100

Comment: can you show me how to display the name of the third image in the array?

Comment: I did not understand your answer.. especially how to access the third image in the array to process it. could you explain more, please?

Comment: intVecSort contains the order of the elements. So the third element has the index intVecSort(3)

Answer (score 0):

This [file exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort-nat--natural-order-sort) can also come in handy -

```
sort_nat
```

It can get as input strings of file names and sort them in natural order.

```
>> imgFilesDirName = {'imag1.jpg', 'imag10.jpg', 'imag11.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img20.jpg'};
>> sort_nat(imgFilesDirName)

ans = 

    'imag1.jpg'    'imag10.jpg'    'imag11.jpg'    'img2.jpg'    'img20.jpg'
```

---

Disclaimer: I copied the text directly from Matlab file exchange, it is not mine in any way

```
function [cs,index] = sort_nat(c,mode)
    % Set default value for mode if necessary.
    if nargin < 2
        mode = 'ascend';
    end

    % Make sure mode is either 'ascend' or 'descend'.
    modes = strcmpi(mode,{'ascend','descend'});
    is_descend = modes(2);
    if ~any(modes)
        error('sort_nat:sortDirection',...
            'sorting direction must be ''ascend'' or ''descend''.')
    end

    % Replace runs of digits with '0'.
    c2 = regexprep(c,'\d+','0');

    % Compute char version of c2 and locations of zeros.
    s1 = char(c2);
    z = s1 == '0';

    % Extract the runs of digits and their start and end indices.
    [digruns,first,last] = regexp(c,'\d+','match','start','end');

    % Create matrix of numerical values of runs of digits and a matrix of the
    % number of digits in each run.
    num_str = length(c);
    max_len = size(s1,2);
    num_val = NaN(num_str,max_len);
    num_dig = NaN(num_str,max_len);
    for i = 1:num_str
        num_val(i,z(i,:)) = sscanf(sprintf('%s ',digruns{i}{:}),'%f');
        num_dig(i,z(i,:)) = last{i} - first{i} + 1;
    end

    % Find columns that have at least one non-NaN.  Make sure activecols is a
    % 1-by-n vector even if n = 0.
    activecols = reshape(find(~all(isnan(num_val))),1,[]);
    n = length(activecols);

    % Compute which columns in the composite matrix get the numbers.
    numcols = activecols + (1:2:2*n);

    % Compute which columns in the composite matrix get the number of digits.
    ndigcols = numcols + 1;

    % Compute which columns in the composite matrix get chars.
    charcols = true(1,max_len + 2*n);
    charcols(numcols) = false;
    charcols(ndigcols) = false;

    % Create and fill composite matrix, comp.
    comp = zeros(num_str,max_len + 2*n);
    comp(:,charcols) = double(s1);
    comp(:,numcols) = num_val(:,activecols);
    comp(:,ndigcols) = num_dig(:,activecols);

    % Sort rows of composite matrix and use index to sort c in ascending or
    % descending order, depending on mode.
    [unused,index] = sortrows(comp);
    if is_descend
        index = index(end:-1:1);
    end
    index = reshape(index,size(c));
    cs = c(index);
end
```